# oracle: Query records where creation date is within 6 months prior to today's date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

If today is Dec 4, 2013, and I want to get all records that are created 6 months before, I should only retrieve the records which are created during:
- Nov 2013
- Oct 2013
- Sep 2013
- Aug 2013
- Jul 2013
- Jun 2013
and i have to group the count by month and year

I have the following columns:
ItemName
UserName
Month
Year
CreateDate

User can create an item or other item several times.  The Month and Year columns are just extracted from the CreateDate.
I want to get the count of items created during the each month (for the 6 months i stated earlier) group by itemName, month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT ItemName,    
       UserName, 
       to_char(createdate, 'MM') month, 
       to_char(createdate, 'YYYY') year, 
       count(*) item_count
FROM   tablename
WHERE  createdate BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -6) AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 1)
GROUP BY ItemName,UserName,to_char(createdate, 'MM'), to_char(createdate, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY month, year;
```

Comment: i would like to order it by createddate however, i am getting not a GROUP BY expression error

Comment: Try to order it by month and year, instead of ordering by createdate. I have slightly modified my answer to order the result by month and year.